# Tailoring blog and categories in Jekyll GitHub

Tags: github, jekyll, categories, blogs

I am testing out Jekyll GitHub and am hoping to tailor a few items on the Blog format. The test site I am specifically referring to is [here](https://testmdrs.github.io/blog/).

1) Sounds to simple, but I am unable to figure out how to tailor the text over the image ("Welcome to the blog") and the initial text in the main container ("My thoughts and ideas"). I see these text in the files [here](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/blob/master/_site/blog/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/blob/master/_site/blog/page2/index.html), representing the first and second pages of the blog it seems. Is it wise to tweak the text in these files directly? Or are these files generated from another source and I should tweak these text from that original source?

2) I managed to create two extra dummy blog posts from the original template by adding .md files (2016-08-29-example-post-three.md and 2019-10-11-example-post-four.md) [to this location](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/tree/master/_posts). Is this the intended way for users (i.e. me) to add posts? It seems sustainable in terms of integrating with the rest of the links etc.

3) I really like the format of the [blog site](https://testmdrs.github.io/blog/). The only thing I would really like to tailor is changing the categories (in this example called "Bioinformatics" and "General" to simply connect to another tab (for example the "Media" tab) without generating categories there. I just would like them all to link to any other website. Is it possible to tailor this?

Any advice for any of these points would be so greatly appreciated. Thank you for sharing any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soory to be brief, but here are the answers:

1. Original source is [here](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/blob/bcfd33c96a7e6875c1a55a9b37155c8826ec602b/_config.yml). You should alter that.
2. Yes.
3. Yes it is possible, the code is [here](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/blob/484acda359eac3c8aad7977acb0d7801306eed53/_includes/post-meta.html).